# Replace empty string with Null Values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with column TotalCharges which is string type, it has some some empty values, I want null to be printed instead of those empty spaces.

Column right now

```
**************
|1671.6                           |
|8003.8                           |
|680.05                           |
|6130.85                          |
|1415                             |
|6201.95                          |
|                                 |
|74.35                            |
|6597.25                          |
```

Expected Output

```
|1671.6                           |
|8003.8                           |
|680.05                           |
|6130.85                          |
|1415                             |
|6201.95                          |
|Null                             |
|74.35                            |
|6597.25                          |
```

Comment: can you please tell what have you tried to achieve this? Are you facing any issues?

Comment: I tried df.na.replace(Seq("TotalCharges"),Map(" "->"Null"))

Comment: Df.withColumn("TotalCharges", when($"TotalCharges" !==, $"TotalCharges"))

Comment: I have tried both of these queries but I still get an empty string

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{when,lit, _}
df.withColumn("TotalCharges", when(col("name") === lit(""), null).otherwi
se(col("TotalCharges")))
```

Comment: This will print Null value in place of empty string?

Comment: Don't think there is a `then()` method in the column class, but this should work: `df.withColumn("TotalCharges", when(col("TotalCharges") == "", None).else(col("TotalCharges"))`

Comment: sorry, yes I forgot about the syntaxe; I corrected it it's been while

Comment: <console>:1: error: identifier expected but 'else' found.

df.withColumn("TotalCharges", when(col("TotalCharges") == "", None).else(col("TotalCharges"))

Comment: copy paste my answer not else it's otherwise that should be used

Answer (score 0):

Below way will give you `null` for the column when String is `""`

```
df.withColumn("TotalCharges",when($"TotalCharges"!=="",$"TotalCharges"))
```

And this will give you "Null" string in place:

```
df.withColumn("TotalCharges",when($"TotalCharges"==="","Null").otherwise($"TotalCharges"))
```

Comment: Both of these did not work and I can still see the empty spaces.

Comment: The column TotalCharges is a string column, should I convert it to integer first?